# How does Cons save data (Rust Linked List)

Tags: data-structures, rust, linked-list, cons

I have been learning Rust and decided doing some basic type would help to learn the language at a deeper level.

The ["Rust by Example"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/custom_types/enum/testcase_linked_list.html) page for linked lists states

> Ln 4: // Cons: Tuple struct that wraps an element and a pointer to the next node

Which I think means that it is recursively creating the list by always making an empty node to populate with `Cons`.

```
enum linkedList
{
    Head(Head), // Front Pointer and list metrics
    Cons(Arc<linkedList>, isize), //(Data, Next Value) Cons is apparently a LISP construct
    Tail(isize), // Rear Pointer
    Nil //Used to drop the stream
}
```

My real question is what is the underlying mechanism that allows data to be stored in the `Arc<linkedList>` node? I thought it would take a generic (`<T>`) to store the data on the list but apparently this is incorrect.

p.s I am under the impression ARC and BOX smart pointers are interchangeable but used for different purposes. I was trying to make a thread safe version of a single ended rollover safe linked list, sort of like a circular queue.

Comment: really rust by example is old and really bad, forget linked list in Rust please

Comment: Its not great for sure @Stargateur but I am using it to just improve my knowledge. Otherwise <Vec> and <DeVec> are significantly better to use for performance, memory usage and ease. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: If you are interested specifically in linked lists, there is a whole book for you: [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/)

Comment: This is why I love stack overflow, where else would I find knowledge that this book exists. Thanks @IvanC

Comment: Its not clear to me where the confusion lies. Are you not sure how `enum T { A(B, C) }` stores its data? or how `Arc` works?

Comment: Am I missing something? The RbE page you linked doesn't contain this `enum` definition. So what is this? Your own invention? What do you mean "I thought it would take a generic to store the data on the list"... the data in RbE is just a `u32`. Are you talking about RbE's code or your own? What is the significance of adding `Head` and `Tail` variants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation slightly deviates from the standard definition of Cons lists. The straight-forward definition (similar to how you would do it in Lisp) is

```rust
type Data = isize;

enum List {
    Nil,
    Cons(Box<List>, Data),
}
```

As you can see, the `Cons` variant is made up of the nested list and this nodes data element. In your case, each node has an `isize`.

If you have an `Arc<List>` or `Box<List>`, this nested `List` object could be the `Cons` variant too and carry another `isize`. `Arc` and `Box` don't care about what they are pointing to.

---

There are some things that are not quite idiomatic. Having both the `Tail` and `Nil` variant doesn't make much sense, because now you have two ways to signal the end of the list. Similarly, having the `Head` be a variant of the list is strange, because the head of the list is only at the beginning, your implementation allows for a `Head` variant in the middle of the list though.

It is preferable to not have an extra `Nil` node to signal the end of the list. Instead, the last node knows that it is the last (like your `Tail` variant) so that you don't have an extra allocation for the empty node. This is what I would perceive as an idiomatic definition of a singly linked list in Rust:

```rust
struct List {
    // ...
    // extra info for list head
    // ...

    first_node: Option<Box<ListNode>>,
}

struct ListNode {
    value: Data,
    next: Option<Box<ListNode>>,
}
```

To make this generic, we simply have to remove our type alias `Data` from earlier and make it a generic parameter instead:

```rust
struct ListNode<T> {
    value: T,
    next: Option<Box<ListNode<T>>>,
}
```

---

About `Box` and `Arc`: `Box` is an owned pointer to a value on the heap, that means only this one box owns the memory it points to. `Arc` is a thread safe version of `Rc`, which is a reference-counted heap value. Multiple `Rc`-pointers to this memory can exist and read it, the number of these is counted. Thus, the ownership may be shared.

You should pick which to use, based on whether or not you want to create more reference-counted pointers to the nodes (note that you probably want either `Rc<RefCell<Node>>` or `Arc<Mutex<Node>>` to also mutate the list after creating it). If you only ever have the head of the list and want to iterate over it, pick `Box` instead.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I was assuming the Cons(isize) was a pointer to the data Arc<linkedList> when it was actually the other way around. And yeah I was using Arc due to wanting to be able to read from multiple threads but no mutex because I wanted it Immutable to any but the actual owner. Probably just use Box<> instead since it is the only owner of the list then. Thanks!